# Problem with custom routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this line in routes:

```
map.resources :questions, :new => {:vote_for => :put, :vote_against => :put}, :has_many => :replies, :shallow => true
```

And I use the following helpers in my view:

```
link_to 'OK', vote_for_question_path(@question), :method => :put
link_to 'NO', vote_against_question_path(@question), :method => :put
```

But unfortunately there is something wrong with my code, as Rails says:

```
undefined method `vote_for_question_path' for #
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your route syntax is wrong.

If you want to add new member routes (i.e. ones that apply to a single instance of a resource), then you should do:

```
map.resources :questions,
              :member => { :vote_for => :put, :vote_against => :put },
              :has_many => :replies, :shallow => true
```

On the other hand, if you want to override the standard "new" URL segment, then it would be:

```
map.resources :questions, :path_names => { :new => 'vote_for' },
              :has_many => :replies, :shallow => true
```

—Note that the corresponding controller action would still be named "new". This would allow URLs such as:

/questions/vote_for

However, looking at what you appear to be trying to do you might want to consider creating a new `Vote` resource. This would get created when a user votes for a question and would fit within the standard Rails' RESTful routing conventions. Voting on a question could then have a URL something like:

/questions/22/votes/new

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'd like to use the RESTful conventions (as you suggested), but I have no idea how to specify whether the vote is +1 or -1 using /questions/22/votes/new :(

Comment: It's difficult to give you guidance without knowing more about your application. The general idea is that your Question model would be associated with the Vote model, which would probably be associated with a User model. When I user voted on a question, that Vote instance would be added to the collection of Votes for that Question. For a -1 it would be removed.